# Regex- Validation (validate string with not more than 1 space in between)

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a solution where I match a string without 2 or more spaces.
I have checked multiple answer where they are giving the string where string have multiple spaces but I want the opposite like `(abc bb)` is my matching string not `(abc  bb or abc   bb etc)`.

This my validation code

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9\_\- ]+){5,255}$/
```

What I am checking
length should be 5 to 255 characters long and can have alphabets, numbers, -(hyphen), _(underscore) or space only.

** String without multiple spaces in between should not a valid match.

```
abc bb => match
abcd  => not match (only 4 characters)
abc d => match
   bbv => not match (only 3 characters)
b b v => match
abc  bb => not match
abc   bb => not match
abc    bb => not match
There is  a   very good question => Not match
There is a very good question => match
The thing  might  not   go   your way => not match
The thing might not go your way => match

Thanks
```

Comment: All of your sample strings have 1 or 2 words.  Might your project data actually have 3 or more words in a string?  It is important that you sufficiently demonstrate the variability of your project data so that contributors can best answer your question.  Please clarify your [mcve].

Comment: Would a 255 character string containing only spaces be a match?  Is it a requirement to have at least one visible character?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes that's true, I have added more examples. thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit after the updated question:

You could first assert the allowed format of only max a single space in between, and then match 5-255 characters followed by optional spaces.

```
^ *+(?=[\w-]++(?> ?[\w-]+)*+ *$)[\w -]{4,254}[\w-] *$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `*+` Match optional spaces using a possessive quantifier (do not backtrack)
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that on the right is

  - `[\w-]++` Match 1+ word chars or `-`
  - `(?> ?[\w-]+)*+` Repeat matching an optional space followed by 1+ occurrences of `\w` or `-` in an atomic group
  - `*$` Match optional spaces till end of string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[\w -]{4,254}[\w-]` Match 4 to 254 occurrences of either `\w`   or `-`
- `*` Match optional spaces
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C1Ilch/1)

Example code

```
$strings = [
    "abc bb",
    "abc d",
    "b b v",
    "There is a very good question",
    "The thing might not go your way",
    "abcd",
    "   bbv",
    "abc  bb",
    "abc   bb",
    "abc    bb",
    "There is  a   very good question",
    "The thing  might  not   go   your way"
];

$pattern = "/^ *+(?=[\w-]++(?> ?[\w-]+)*+ *$)[\w -]{4,254}[\w-] *$/";

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $s)) {
        echo "Match for: [$s]" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "No match for: [$s]" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match for: [abc bb]
Match for: [abc d]
Match for: [b b v]
Match for: [There is a very good question]
Match for: [The thing might not go your way]
No match for: [abcd]
No match for: [   bbv]
No match for: [abc  bb]
No match for: [abc   bb]
No match for: [abc    bb]
No match for: [There is  a   very good question]
No match for: [The thing  might  not   go   your way]
```

Comment: Since trailing spaces are allowed, you can even shorten it to `^(?=.{5,255}$) *(?>[\w-]+ ?)+ *$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That is a nifty pattern with the atomic group :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird , thanks for your nice explanation, sorry my mistake, these 2
(Match for: [abcd  ]
Match for: [   bbv ])
should not be a match as leading and trailing space should not be count as characters.

Comment: @rkrathor are you not interested in `trim()`ing your values before evaluating them?

Comment: @mickmackusa, the thing is, if I will trim and then check , in this case it will be less than 5 characters. so it will automatically not what we looking for.
and I have to first trim than regex, so if we can manage that from regex only than why not go with that instead of additional trim.

Comment: ... code readability.

Comment: said correctly but if we want to use like this than?
<input type="text" id="textr" class="form-control square" name="textr" placeholder="Specify textr" data-validation-regex-regex="([A-Za-z0-9\_\- ]){5,255}" data-validation-regex-message="Must be 5-255 characters long and can have alphabets, numbers, -(hyphen), _(underscore) or space only" maxlength="255">

Comment: @rkrathor: your system looks complicated and produces an enormous html content for nothing very helpful for the user. It's useless to forbid consecutive spaces and to display an error message, it's better to automatically trim the string, to remove consecutive spaces when the input tag looses the focus and then to check the number of characters. The user needs assistance and not punishement! Instead of trying to put a god validation regex in the html, use the name attribute to link your input tag to a sanitization/validation function on client side (javascript) and on server side (php).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thanks for the comment, you are right and I know what your are suggesting but limitation is there.

Comment: Thank you very much @Thefourthbird for your quick response and help.

Answer (score 2):

Edited answer, after edited question. You could try:

```
^ *+(?!.+?  \S)[\w -]{4,254}[\w-] *$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PbPsT/1)

---

- `^ *+` - Start-line anchor followed by 0+ (Possessive, not giving back) spaces;
- `(?!.+?  \S)` - A negative lookahead to prevent any line to have two space characters inbetween non-whitespace chars;
- `[\w -]{4,254}[\w-]` - Match any word-character, hyphen or space 4-254 times before the last hyphen/word-character;
- `*$` - 0+ (Greedy) spaces before end-line anchor.

Comment: Sorry, no, it was a bad idea, it doesn't work with two space separated with a letter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, no worries. The whole question has just changed so changed the answer too.

Comment: That is a good one `space *+` I kinda borrowed it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll offer a pattern that will ignore leading and trailing spaces, obey the salvageable string length, and ensure that multiple spaces do not exist in the salvageable string.

But first, let's simply your length requirement by reducing 255 to 10 ...just for the sake of unit testing.  In my answer, assume that I am validating for a string length between 5 and 10 characters (instead of 5 and 255).

My suggested pattern will allow leading spaces, match the first word-or-dash character, then match any character 3 to 8, then the last word-or-dash character, then allow trailing spaces.  1+3+1 gives the minimum 5 characters and 1+8+1 gives the maximum 10 characters.  For the asked question, use 1+3+1 and 1+253+1 to sum up to the desired length limit: `{5,255}`.

```
^ *             #match start of string then zero or more allowable/uncountable spaces
[\w-]           #match first word-or-dash character
(?=             #lookahead
   .{3,8}       #match to any character 3 to 8 times to enforce length requirements
   [\w-]        #match last word-or-dash character
    *$          #match allowable/uncountable trailing spaces then end of string
) ?             #close lookahead, then match zero or one space
(?>[\w-]+ ?)+   #repeatedly match one or more word-or-dash sequences followed by zero or one space
 *$             #match zero or more spaces until the end of the string
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CUKPD))

```
$tests = [
    '123 56',
    ' 1234',
    '1234 ',
    '123 5',
    '   1234',
    '    1234    ',
    ' 1 3 5 7 9 ',
    '  1 3 5 7 9   ',
    '   12 45 78 01',
    '   12 45 78 0 ',
    '  1234567890  ',
    ' 12345678901 ',
    '1 3 5 7 9  ',
    '1 3 5 7 9 1',
    '1 3 5 7 9 ',
    '1 3  6 8',
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    printf(
        "'%s' => %s or %s\n",
        $test,
        preg_match('/^ *[\w-](?=.{3,8}[\w-] *$) ?(?>[\w-]+ ?)+ *$/', $test) ? 'pass' : 'fail',
        preg_match('/^(?=.{5,10}$)(?>[\w-]+ ?)+$/', trim($test)) ? 'pass' : 'fail'
    );
}
```

Output:

```
'123 56' => pass or pass
' 1234' => fail or fail
'1234 ' => fail or fail
'123 5' => pass or pass
'   1234' => fail or fail
'    1234    ' => fail or fail
' 1 3 5 7 9 ' => pass or pass
'  1 3 5 7 9   ' => pass or pass
'   12 45 78 01' => fail or fail
'   12 45 78 0 ' => pass or pass
'  1234567890  ' => pass or pass
' 12345678901 ' => fail or fail
'1 3 5 7 9  ' => pass or pass
'1 3 5 7 9 1' => fail or fail
'1 3 5 7 9 ' => pass or pass
'1 3  6 8' => fail or fail
```